# How to "increase" size of VisibleRegion on Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to set visible markers when are inside the visible region of the screen. At this point I'm able to achieve:

```
this.googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener {
    val bounds = this.googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
    for (marker in this.markersUpForList) {
        if (bounds.contains(marker.position)) {
          marker.isVisible = true
        //... do more stuff
        } else {
          marker.isVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to load markers a little "far away" from this visible region to "prevent" when user does some scroll. We assume that if user scrolls to far away, markers "will appear later".

So my question is how to calculate this "extra" space. I don't know if for example add some decimals to latlan southwest/northeast point or I need some specific math

[image]

Comment: It should be dependent on the zoom-level as well. But it doesn't sound like a task requiring more math than expanding the bounds by a reasonable linear amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For “increase” size of `bounds` you can use [Affine Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) (scale) e.g. like in this method:

```
private static LatLngBounds scaleBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, float scale, Projection projection) {
    LatLng center = bounds.getCenter();
    Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(center);

    Point screenPositionNortheast = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.northeast);
    screenPositionNortheast.x = (int) (scale * (screenPositionNortheast.x - centerPoint.x) + centerPoint.x);
    screenPositionNortheast.y = (int) (scale * (screenPositionNortheast.y - centerPoint.y) + centerPoint.y);
    LatLng scaledNortheast = projection.fromScreenLocation(screenPositionNortheast);

    Point screenPositionSouthwest = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.southwest);
    screenPositionSouthwest.x = (int) (scale * (screenPositionSouthwest.x - centerPoint.x) + centerPoint.x);
    screenPositionSouthwest.y = (int) (scale * (screenPositionSouthwest.y - centerPoint.y) + centerPoint.y);
    LatLng scaledSouthwest = projection.fromScreenLocation(screenPositionSouthwest);

    LatLngBounds scaledBounds = new LatLngBounds(scaledSouthwest, scaledNortheast);

    return scaledBounds;
}
```

And you can use it like that way:

```
...
val scaleFactor = 1.5f;  // increase size 1.5 times
val bounds = projection.getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
val scaledBounds = scaleBounds(bounds, scaleFactor, projection);

for (marker in this.markersUpForList) {
    if (scaledBounds .contains(marker.position)) {
      marker.isVisible = true
    //... do more stuff
    } else {
      marker.isVisible = false
    }
}
```